# Why can't I set the property value of a class object without being in a method?

Tags: c#, function, object

I was having trouble setting properties and realized I could only set the properties within a function or method. My question is why is this the case?

Here is my code that works:

```
public class SomeClass
{    
    Car car = new Car();

    public Car JustAMethod()
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.year = 2012;

        return car;
    }        
}
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
public class SomeClass
{        
    Car car = new Car();
    car.year = 2012;//I get an error here
}
```

Comment: that's what constructors are for;)

Comment: Constructors are becoming a forgotten art. I sometimes wish object initializers never happened. With a constructor, you're telling the consuming code exactly what is necessary to create a valid object. With initializers, the client code can hork the object any way it wants to.

Comment: @BobHorn I think both constructors and object initializers have their valid uses. A constructor should require all the information needed to construct a valid object; the object initializer can be used to supply option information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language specification (for the most part) forbids the execution of arbitrary statements at the class level. All that can be done is to specify default values for static or instance members of the class.

All code, generally speaking, must be executed within methods of a class.

[As AntLaC mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198232/129655), you can get around this by specifying the value using the object initialization syntax. Since objects can be defined at the class level (as "default values for static or instance members"), using syntax like the below will also work:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    Car car = new Car() {
        year = 2012;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because that is the way the language specification requires it.

Imagine the mess that would happen if it were possible to write anything anywhere you liked:
We'd have ended up with PHP, and that was certainly *not* a design goal of C#.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set specific properties you can try this without being in a method

```
Car car = new Car()
          {
             year = 2012
          };
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue that arbitrary code simply cannot be executed at the class level, but must be in a method. (Static and non-static class variables can be set, but that's about it.) How important that is depends on what the questioner is really asking, which is somewhat unclear. (Not downvoting, just wanted to mention it.)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure not every answer has to address every possible aspect of the question. This happens to be one of the most helpful ones in my opinion.

Comment: I agree absolutely, in fact I'm even giving you an upvote. I'm trying to enhance the answer by contrasting it with a different issue :-)

Comment: I agree with @PlatinumAzure. This doesn't answer the question "Why one could only set the properties within a function or method". The fact that the language provides syntax sugar to make it look like it actually does allow setting properties outside a method is rather irrelevant imo.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that those are just the rules of the language. However, you have a few options:

> Create a constructor so that Car takes a year:

```
public class SomeClass
{        
    Car car = new Car(2012);
}
```

> Use object initializers:

```
public class SomeClass
{        
    Car car = new Car() { Year = 2012 };
}
```

> ```
> Use a method:
> ```

```
public class SomeClass
{        
    Car car = InitializeCar(2012);

    private Car InitializeCar(int year)
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.Year = 2012;

        return car;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the property in that way, it isn't allowed. You can do it in a constructor/ in a method/in a property. Or in this way:

```
public class SomeClass{        
    Car car = new Car(){ year = 2012 };
}
```

Or you can pass to the constructor your value:

```
public class Car{
    public int year;
    public Car(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class SomeClass{        
    Car car = new Car(2012);
}
```